# Python forgetting variable name?

Tags: python, configuration

I'm learning Python and I'm have some issues.

**I got this error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_console.py", line 8, in <module>
    from util import Util
  File "../utils/util.py", line 13, in <module>
    class Util:
  File "../utils/util.py", line 73, in Util
    config.write(configfile)
NameError: name 'config' is not defined
```

Following is my code (this is inside a function):

```
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

    for index, list in enumerate(my_list):
        config.add_section(str(index))
        config.set(str(index), 'id', list.name)
        config.set(str(index), 'host', list.host)

    # Creating the folder
    myFolder = "/etc/element/"
    if not os.path.exists(myFolder):
        os.makedirs(myFolder)

    # Creating the file
    filePath = "/etc/element/settings.cfg"
    with open(filePath, 'wb') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

Note: I'm using Sublime Text 3 as IDE. "myFolder" have the same problem a little time ago - if I type `filePath = myFolder + '/settings.cfg'` I got the same error of "not defined". Finally, I imported ConfigParser as following: `import ConfigParser`.

### Is Python forgetting my variable name or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You forgot to save your files or your IDE is not reloading modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Thanks for replies, but I found the solution.

I go to Nano and edit the file with this error, so I see the indentation is absolutaly wrong. **It was just a Sublime text 3 issue, now's solved.**

Comment: Maybe you should mark this as the solution then. Glad you found it. Most python programmers make sure to set their editors so that tabs are replaced with spaces to avoid this type of problem - especially if they work in a group. Not everybody uses the same tab stops.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. But this is a Sublime Text issue or just a bad config?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible ConfigParser or some other import also defines a config variable that is being used by your config.write().

Sometimes it is safer to just import the functions you need, that way you know exactly what is defined in your file.  It means you have to explicitly import everything that you use in other files, but it prevents any unknown duplication in your namespace.

You would do this like:

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser  # instead of import ConfigParser

# Then
config = ConfigParser()
```

Secondly, config is a common variable - try renaming it to something like myConfig and see if it still happens.

Comment: I made the changes you tell, but I still having troubles. As a note, in another method in the same class I instantiate another ConfigParser, but with another name. I need to fix that? (If yes, how?)

Answer (score 1):

configfile is the object that you want to use for write(). You are using a parser to write.

Comment: If I change what you said, the error persist, but thanks for try help me.

Comment: You have not told us which line is "line 73". Is it one of the ones that you are showing?

Comment: Is this line: `config.write(configfile)`

Comment: The error message does not really make sense. That said, the incomplete function shown does not help. But your config shown, should not be the object of the write function. Your function should be configfile.write (something)

Comment: See above comment. You are probably not really executing the code that you show. Did you save the file? Save it, then run it again.

Comment: yes, I saved the file and run it two times. But I will do one more time because you. Soon the result.

Comment: Still having the issue: 'File "../utils/util.py", line 74, in Util
    configfile.write(config)
NameError: name 'config' is not defined'